# Conditional Action Call

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, unified-service-desk

I'm building an application using CRM 2013 Unified Service Desk (USD). Right now, I'm creating a conditional action call from a hosted control to another. So far I got it working with a single expression, like:

```
"[[Data1]]" == "Value1"
```

But I've gone further down the rabbit's hole and now I need to query two values with an OR operator:

```
"[[Data1]]" == "Value1" || "[[Data2]]" == "Value2"
```

While the first example works fine, using the || operator does not. I've already tried using some variations, like expr OR expr, but the evaluation fails.

There's no documentation on MSDN covering the conditional part of an action call, so I need help figuring this one out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have discovered,  USD translates your key's to their text versions and then passes it to the javascript converter. 
so :

```
// where mykey1 = "Test" (string)  and mykey2 = true (bool)
// Success condition
"[[mykey1]]" == "Test" || "[[mykey2]]" == "True"
```

if you were working with a lookup and you want to only run the action if the lookup is pointed at the business unit and the name of the business unit is defaultorg... you would use this:

```
// where [[$User.businessunitid]] reference to a business unit
"[[$User.businessunitid.logicalname]]" == "businessunit" && "[[$User.businessunitid.name]]" == "defaultorg"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Helps a lot, thanks Matt. I was curious whether USD was using Javascript (which I suspected from scriptlets) or C# to interpret the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a little experimenting, I realized that the issue was not with the logical operators but with a boolean representation instead. `true` and `false` are capitalized in USD conditionals:

```
"[[Data1]]" == "Value1" || "[[Data2]]" == "True"
```

But the rest of the expression was valid, so you can combine and use logical ORs ("||") and logical ANDs ("&&") just as you'd do in C#.